# How to Vectorizationdataframe pandas daframe with list in condition?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to Vectorization my dataframe with NumPy arrays but I got an error

Here is the code :

#### Here I initialize my dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1.,
                    'B': pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'C': pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype='float32'),
                    'D': [True,False,True,False],
                    'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "Draft", "test", "Draft"]),
                    'F': 'foo'})
df2
```

output:

```
    A   B           C   D       E       F
0   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 True    test    foo
1   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 False   Draft   foo
2   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 True    test    foo
3   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 False   train   foo
```

#### Here I define the function to apply to dataframe's columns

```
def IsBillingValid2(xE,yBilling):
    
    if(xE not in ['Draft','Cancelled'] and yBilling==True): #Order Edited
        return True
    
    else:      
        return False
```

#### Here I launch my function

```
df2['BillingPostalCode_Det_StageName_Det']=IsBillingValid(df2['E'].values,df2['D'].values)
```

#### Here is the Error:

output:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2946139111570059> in <module>
     16         return False
     17 
---> 18 df2['BillingPostalCode_Det_StageName_Det']=IsBillingValid(df2['E'].values,df2['D'].values)
     19 

<command-2041881674588848> in IsBillingValid(xStageName, yBilling)
    207 def IsBillingValid(xStageName,yBilling):
    208 
--> 209     if(xStageName not in ['Draft','Cancelled'] and yBilling==True): #Order Edited
    210         return True
    211 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `apply` especially when you want vectorized operation.

Use `pandas.Series.isin`:

```
df2['BillingPostalCode_Det_StageName_Det'] = ~df2["E"].isin({"Draft", "Cancelled"}) & df2["D"]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
     A          B    C      D      E    F  BillingPostalCode_Det_StageName_Det
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0   True   test  foo                                 True
1  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  False  Draft  foo                                False
2  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0   True   test  foo                                 True
3  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  False  Draft  foo                                False
```